# how to quickly count sequence values ​in python

Tags: python, numpy

```py
import random

number_points = 10000
xx = []
x = 1
for _ in range(number_points):
    number = random.randint(20, 35)
    x = x * number
    xx.append(x)
```

I have a code that counts a sequence where the next member depends on the previous one

Can I somehow speed this up with numpy?

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

number_points = 10000
numbers = np.random.randint(20, 35, size=number_points)
xx = np.cumprod(numbers)
```

- In this code, we use `np.random.randint` to generate an array of random integers between 20 and 35 directly.
- Then, we use `np.cumprod` to calculate the cumulative product of the  array.
- This eliminates the need for the loop and individual element-wise  multiplication, making your code more efficient.